# Not Getting ClientID of Checkbox in Onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have the following ASP form and corresponding client-side script. Why am I not getting the Clientid of chkEverySun in the onclick event of the chkSun checkbox?

```
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSun" name="Sun" type="checkbox" runat="server" onclick="SetDayCheckBox(this.id,'<%= chkEverySun.ClientID %>');" />                      


        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkEverySun" name="Sun" type="checkbox" runat="server" />

<script>
    function SetDayCheckBox(tocheckid,touncheckid) {
                alert(tocheckid);
                alert(touncheckid);
}
</script>
```

Comment: The `function` needs to be in `<script>` tags perhaps?

Comment: in my code this javascript function is already in script tags

Answer (score 0):

instead of '<%= chkEverySun.ClientID %>' try:

```
`$('#<%= chkEverySun.ClientID %>')`
```

as

```
onclick="SetDayCheckBox(this.id,$('#<%= chkEverySun.ClientID %>'));"
```

Comment: onclick="SetDayCheckBox(this.id,$('#<%= chkEverySun.ClientID %>'));" - too many ' try now

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
$('#test').click( function() {alert($(this).attr('id'))});
```

here "test" is checkbox id.